# Is it possible to have an old question appear as a new question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have an issue that is similar to one discussed in a question a long time ago. An answer to this question could also answer my question, however it was not answered such that it solved my problem. What can I do to make it appear again as a active question so that more users will want to answer it?

Comment: You can add a bounty on it, then it will both attract people's attention and you get to specify what is lacking in the current answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the question, possibly adding your own explanations as to why the extant answers are inadequate. This assumes your question is not "substantially" different from the older one. (What "substantial" is in that case can of course be subjective.)

Comment: You need to update your blog. The last date is December 21, 2014.There are a lot of interesting thing. Could resume the updates. :)

Comment: I certainly should, but alas I am busy with so many other things. :(