# Would like more detailed guidance on duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

I understand that, to avoid cluttering the site, one should avoid asking questions that have already been answered (though there is this:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

But what if you have a good question that is similar to one that was asked a few years ago that was either never fully answered, or not answered at all?  In this case, it's clearly possible that asking it again might gain an answer, either because different people would be looking at it, someone that looked at it previously might have a new idea, or because MMA now has new capabilities it didn't at the time of the original question.

In that case, what is the proper course of action?

Comment: closely related: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1948/5478

Comment: Agree,especially those link use a old method solve current question but *Mathematica* is alway updating.

Comment: And in some case,actually those link post cannot work out the current question(sometimes).

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks.  It seems my question about duplicate questions was itself a duplicate! [My search missed it.]  When I edit a question (as the linked answer suggests), is it OK to add, for clarity:  "I'm a different user who's editing this question because it was never fully answered [for reason x], and am hoping this will bring it new attention"?  Generally when people edit they do so without calling attention to the edit.  However, since when you edit you are changing someone's words without their permission, I'd feel more comfortable noting the edit explicitly.

Comment: To add to linked answer, if you feel your case deserves a separate topic, ask the question stressing out differences and linking to the original topic.

Comment: Suppose my case doesn't constitute a separate topic, and I merely want to bring new attention to an existing question, to see if someone might now be able to offer an answer.  If I choose to follow the suggestion given in your link (https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/is-it-possible-to-have-an-old-question-appear-as-a-new-question) to edit the question, should I explicitly distinguish my edits from the original question (e.g., using the formulation I suggested in the comment above)?

Comment: @theorist Another standard way is to put a bounty on the old question.

Comment: It's annoying to me when I look for a solution and find a bunch of related questions with one or two epsilon differences. The best answer is in there somewhere, but I can't find it among all the choices. Wouldn't it be nice if it were always found at the linked duplicate? But, you know, the ideal can be hard to obtain.